# How to work with android different resolutions?

Tags: android

How large should be the image in pixels to fit all resolutions?
480x800 or 480x854?

I need to do different image resolutions for all folders:drawable-hdpi , drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi?and if so, which resolutions are used?

Thanks

Comment: Note that resolution is separate from density. For example, the G1 is a medium DPI device with a 320x480 screen. The Samsung Galaxy Tab is also a medium DPI device, but with a 7", 1024x600 display. For this reason, you also need to take into account the "large" resource qualifier.

Comment: You should also use nine-patch images where possible, so that you have to create fewer graphics and don't have to worry about the exact device screen dimensions so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an image that will fill the entire screen?  There are over 50 supported android phones, each with a different resolution.  You can't expect to create an image of the exact size of each phone.  Instead, you'll probably need to come up with a few different versions and then allow it to stretch to fill the full screen.

hdpi, ldpi, mdpi refers the density of pixels on the screen, not the screen size.  Thus, one mdpi screen might be 320x480 while another might be 480x854.

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has lots of good information dealing with the different screen sizes and densities.  [Icon design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) has specific suggestions for pixels sizes for different icons at the different screen densities.

Answer (score 0):

Jovan, without knowing the type and context of the image you are referring to, this is difficult for me to answer directly.  I assume you have drawn the 480x800 / 480x854 numbers from the high density WVGA and FWVGA total screen sizes.  The android developer article on screen size support may help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your app will target multiple device with different densities.
Please check the table in the link bellows to see the different resolutions in each folder:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html